# Can't use the FXMLLoader#setRoot

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I am trying to run this Tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

I want to run it on Eclipse. I downloaded the zip-project from the bottom of the site. I tried to copy the 3 files: CustomControl.java, CustomControlExample.java and custom_control.fxml.

However the CustomControl.java got an error. I can't use the `setRoot` and the `setController` Method on `fxmlLoader` which is an object of `FXMLLoader`.

How can I fix that problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your JavaFX version is prior to 2.2. To determine the version used put:

```
System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
```

then update it by updating to the latest JDK. Don't forget to check/configure Eclipse Java/JavaFX platform.

Comment: @csnewb, you are welcome. Also welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a tour on the [StackOverflow About Page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) before actively using this site.